# C# How to Run User Control button click Event in Other User Control panel

Tags: c#, winforms

frnd, My usercontrol02 have method.  i need run other user control(usercontrol01) in use usercontrol02 method. plz fix this code

```
 ((usercontrol02)Application.OpenForms["usercontrol02"]).MyMethod();
```

Comment: WebForms? WinForms? WPF? Anything else?

Comment: "plz fix this code" ??

Comment: You want to call a method of some control from another control, right?

Comment: no. windows Form only

Comment: M Adeel Khalid - YES

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with events then you can call one control's event in another controls event. for example if you have two buttons button1 and button2 and both have click event attached. then you can call button1's click  event in button2's click event like this:

```
button2_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1_click(sender, null);
}
```

I hope this will do the job for you.